# ScalaJSReact Uncaught referenceError in React.scala

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-react

I'm trying out scalajsReact with this hello world example:

```
object ScalaJSExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val NoArgs =
      ScalaComponent.static(<.div("Hello!"))
    NoArgs().renderIntoDOM(document.body)
}
```

But I get this runtime error: `Uncaught ReferenceError:: React.scala:41`

I am using scalajsReact 1.7.5 and React 16.13.1.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I used https://github.com/vmunier/play-scalajs.g8 to seed my project and somehow the bundling was not done properly using this setup. Base on ScalaJsBundler doc, I replaced WebScalaJS with WebScalaJSBundlerPlugin and I worked.